# When may the bar resolution be truncated for calculating $\operatorname{hocolim}$?

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Suppose $D$ is a small category and $F\colon D\to sSets$ a functor. I want to calculate the simplicial set $$\operatorname{hocolim}F$$
via the [bar construction](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bar+construction): $\operatorname{hocolim}F$ is the diagonal of the bisimplicial set
$$
\ldots\begin{array}{c}\to \\ \vdots\\\to\end{array}\coprod_{d_{k}\to ...\to d_0}F(d_{k})\begin{array}{c}\to \\ \vdots\\\to\end{array}...\begin{array}{c}\to \\ \to\\\to\end{array}\coprod_{d_1\to d_0}F(d_1)\begin{array}{c}\to\\\to\end{array}\coprod_{d_0}F(d_0).
$$
which is called the bar resolution $BF\colon \Delta^{op}\to sSets$. We have also $\operatorname{hocolim}F = \operatorname{hocolim}BF$ by [Bousfield-Kan](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bousfield-Kan+map).

In some cases, it seems to be sufficient to consider only the $k$-truncation of $BF\colon \Delta^{op}\to sSets$. For example, if $D=\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$
\operatorname{hocolim}F= \operatorname{hocolim}\left(
\coprod_{d_1\to d_0}F(d_1)\begin{array}{c}\to\\\to\end{array}\coprod_{d_0}F(d_0)\right).
$$
As explained in in the answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135077/three-questions-on-operatornamehocolim) question on MO, one may consider the $k$-truncation of $BF$, if the [nerve](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve) $ND$ of $D$ is $k$-skeletal. However, the nerve $N\mathbb{N}$ is **not** $1$-skeletal and it suffices nevertheless to consider the $1$-truncation of the bar resolution. [Apparently](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135077/three-questions-on-operatornamehocolim) it does not suffice to observe that $N\mathbb{N}$ is contractible.

> Why does this suffice for $D=\mathbb{N}$ and are there some easy to formulate conditions on $D$ such that one may take the $k$-truncated bar resolution for calculating $\operatorname{hocolim}F$?

Comment: You have to understand the formula correctly. The subtlety is in the indexing of the first coproduct: it's not a coproduct over _all_ arrows in $\mathbb{N}$, just the generators.

Comment: Dear Zhen Lin, sorry but I don't understand what you mean. In $(BF)_1$, it is a coproduct indexed by *all* morphisms of $D$, right? Do you mean, that the indexing of the truncated bar resolution I wrote below is different?

Comment: What I am saying is that the formula works _if_ you change the coproduct.

Comment: The second formula. The first formula is the definition.

Comment: Do you mean in the second formula or in the first? The first is actually defined with indexing over *all* morphisms, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you. What is the reason that this works for $\mathbb{N}$ and not for an arbitrary $D$?

Comment: Because $\mathbb{N}$ is a free category.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. Does this mean that for any free category, I may restrict to the $1$-truncation? Thank you.

Comment: No, you can't even do that for $\mathbb{N}$. You have to restrict to a suitable subcomplex of the 1-truncated bar complex.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wrote something silly. What I meant was: Does it work for any free category $D$ when I index the second coproduct in by the edges of the graph defining $D$? (probably those edges are called ''generators'')

Comment: Yes, I expect it should work, but I have never seen it written out explicitly.